# Optimize Python dictionarys look-up in Cython

Tags: python, c++, c, dictionary, cython

I'm trying to improve the speed of this function in Cython, because is the main function of an algorithm.

```
cpdef float _cost(list path, int lenth, dict time, dict cost):
    cdef: 
        float final_cost = 0
        float time_sum = 0
        int count = 0, i=0, 
    
    for i in range(lenth):
        p1 = path[i]
        p2 = path[i+1]
        if time_sum < 8:
            time_sum += time[p1][p2]
            final_cost += cost[p1][p2]
        else:
            time_sum = time[p1][path[0]] + time[path[0]][p2]
            final_cost += cost[p1][path[0]] + cost[path[0]][p2]
            count +=1
            
    final_cost +=  cost[path[0]][path[lenth]]
    return final_cost + count * 9.25 * 2
```

Both dictionaries are formed by an `int` as a key and other dictionary as a value with and `int` as a key and a `float` as a value. In c++ the typing is the following `unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int, float>> cost;`

- One of the first optimizations I did, was write the function in c++ using `unordered_map` but **Python Hash Dictionarys are blazingly fast**. So the code was a little slower.
- The second Optimizations I did improve a little bit the speed. As you can see in the code, `p1` and `p2` variables are not typed, this is because if I type, **Cython have to make a lot of transformations** to adapt the cython int to the dict int type (is not the same that int cython type).

After spend a lot of time researching about how to improve it I can't solve this two questions:

1. Is there any way of type `p1` and `p2` correctly? I think this will improve the speed!.
2. Are there any way to improve this function? maybe there is something that I'm missing...

Comment: You cannot considerable speed up Python's dict. Last time I did comparison with c++-maps, c++ unordered map were slightly faster for look-up (so maybe you did something wrong). There is also dense_hash_map from google, which is even faster than c++'s implementation.

Comment: The code as written doesn't compile (which can't help). Typing `p1` and `p2` is unlikely to improve anything for Python dicts since the only thing you use them for is a `dict` lookup, which requires a generic Python object. You've definitely tried the obvious approaches - maybe this is just as fast as your algorithm goes?

Comment: Wth the `unordered_map` - the main thing would be to make sure that the data stays as an `unordered_map`. You do not want to be copying it to and from a Python `dict`.

Comment: sorry @DavidW the code now compile, I did some mistakes at copy. Sorry. Okay I will see my ```unordered_map``` solution, maybe is something wrong. But I read in a lot of articles than the speed is more or less the same, and in my results the speed is for 1M look-up only 8 hundredths of a difference.

Comment: @ead Thank you very much, I will see the Google Hash Map!

Comment: What is `comida_count`? I don't see it declared anywhere. Is it supposed to be `count`?

Comment: Sorry @ShadowRanger is ```count```. I edit my question

Comment: Would a 2d array work instead of nested `dict`s? It'd depend on how sparse the data is, but would probably be significantly faster if it were feasible?

Comment: I didn't try because it will have to do a lot iterations, for a (3, 3) matrix will be very good but I don't think a matrix (300, 300) will be better than hash dict. I mean you have to look and check if it is the value that you want 300 times (at maximum, less if you find earlier), and after do the same and iterate 300 times and check if is the value you are looking for (second dict). Do you think that all this iterations and check could be better than dict? If you believe it I will check it. But from  my point of view a 2D array should be considerably slower no?

Comment: You shouldn't have to iterate at all. Put the time and cost values for `path[i]` at `time[path[i]]` and `time[cost[i]]`, just as you are doing now with dicts.  The tradeoff here is that you have to allocate two arrays of length max(path[]) and that could be very large.  (Consider using ndarrays for this, or memoryviews.)

Comment: From your code, it looks like there are not only dict accesses to worry about (which are fast and cannot be sped up meaningfully without a bunch of custom code) but also list accesses (every time you are querying path). The list accesses are slow. If you can replace path with a memoryview instead, this could be much faster. If not, at least you can avoid some accesses by cache-ing repeat lookups in a variable (e.g. storing the result of path[0] outside of the loop so you do not need to keep looking it up inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks @CodeSurgeon . The code is too large to post here, but I tryed in the past with memoryviews, ```numpy.ndarrays()``` in C mode and with ```vector``` from STL in C++. And surprisingly, Boths methods were slow than Python list. I was surprise by this fact. To mee seems like ```.append()``` method of Python list is very competitive, and maybe the transformations that you need to do from C++ int to Python int for dictionarys have a big impact. Also probably my C++/memory view/np.ndarray code was not good enough.

Comment: If you are having lots of `append` calls, that does change things quite a bit. It can be costly to resize raw arrays (requiring a call to something like `realloc` behind the scenes), although you could argue the same would be true for python `list` objects (which are really just a variable length array of `PyObject *`. That being said, I can't imagine typing `path` as `int[:] path` would be really slower. Is there some test data to work with (or at least some expected sizes) for `path`, `time`, and `cost` lists/dicts?

Comment: Using what @DavidW said, you could do something like [this](https://gist.github.com/AnishN/1e6c9042ecbafd47e546ffeddf24e2eb) and nearly all python overhead (outside of the function call itself), should disappear. And if length is just the length of path, you could use path.shape[0] instead and save having to pass that in as a parameter.